# How can I concatenate columns and sum values from two data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two data frames (left data frame is 1, the other is 2) and I want to get the final data frame based on the below conditions:

1. Group `Col2` by `Col1`, for example, `A 566,788,888,999,1212`
2. In data frame 2, I can find that the `(Group A) 788,888,999,1212` so I want to keep it, while `566` is not in data frame 2, so ignore it.
3. Sum Total for all members in Data Frame 1 and 2, for example, `A-788(2), A-888(3), A-999(4), A-1212 (5), 788-888(12), 999-1212 (13)`, so `2+3+4+5+12+13 = 39`

---

```
Col1    Col2  Total        Col3   Col4   Total  
 A      566    1            788   888      12
 A      788    2            999   1212     13
 A      888    3            700   707      14
 A      999    4            701   702      15
 A      1212   5
 B      700    6
 B      701    7
 B      702    8
 B      703    9
 B      704    10
 B      705    11
```

Expected Result

```
ResultCol1    ResultCol2           ResultTotal
  A           788,888,999,1212        39
  B           700,701,702             50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` are your initial dataframes:

```
In [345]: common_values = pd.concat([df2.Col3, df2.Col4])

In [346]: def f(x):
     ...:     return pd.Series({'Col2': ','.join(map(str, x.Col2)),
     ...:                       'Total': x.Total.sum() 
     ...:                       + df2[(df2.Col3.isin(x.Col2) | df2.Col4.isin(x.Col2))]['Total'].sum()})
     ...:         

In [347]: df_totals = df1[df1.Col2.isin(common_values)].groupby('Col1').apply(f)

In [348]: df_totals
Out[348]: 
                  Col2  Total
Col1                         
A     788,888,999,1212     39
B          700,701,702     50
```